# How to configure Hibernate in a Maven WebApp running on Wildfly 10?

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa

I created a JSF EJB JPA application in Eclipse and now I would like to use Hibernate. I have a running MariaDB set up, added a datasource to my Standalone.xml and created a module.xml for MySQL.

In my last project (which I did not set up myself) I used to simply create entities with annotations and the tables would be automatically created and I did not need to write any mappings. How do I set this up ? Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
  @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String username;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 4, max = 255)
  @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
  private String password;

  public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }
  // ...
}
```

I read several tutorials, but I am not sure I understood everything.

- Do I need a hibernate.cfg.xml or hibernate.properties ?
- If the Hibernate libs are provided with WildFly 10, do I need to add dependencies in my POM ?
- How and where do I specify that the tables should be created by Hibernate ?
- I used to produce an EntityManager like this:

  ```
  @ApplicationScoped
  public class EntityManagerProducer {

    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Produces
    @Default
    @TransactionScoped
    protected EntityManager exposeEntityManagerProxy() {
      return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    protected void onTransactionEnd(@Disposes @Default EntityManager entityManager) {
      if (entityManager.isOpen()) {
        entityManager.close();
      }
    }
  }
  ```

I would like to use the same class - how does Hibernate know which class to load ? How is this configured ?

UPDATE1: The WildFly CLI returns this after adding the JDBC Driver:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=datasources:installed-drivers-list
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => [{
        "driver-name" => "mysql",
        "deployment-name" => undefined,
        "driver-module-name" => "com.mysql",
        "module-slot" => "main",
        "driver-datasource-class-name" => "",
        "driver-xa-datasource-class-name" => "com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.Mysq
lXADataSource",
        "driver-class-name" => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "driver-major-version" => 5,
        "driver-minor-version" => 1,
        "jdbc-compliant" => false
    }]
}
```

Comment: If you are using JPA (as you say) then you should never need Hibernate specific CFG or properties files! That is the whole point of using JPA

Comment: Well, I selected the JPA facet. I thought that I needed it. Now that you ask, I am not sure anymore. Correct me if I am wroing, I thought Hibernate implemented JPA, but also brings new functionalities. What is the "better" solution ? Or, in other words, which is easier to implement ?

Comment: Read the JPA spec ... JPA works from persistence.xml. Hibernate CFG/properties files are nothing to do with JPA. Yes Hibernate implements JPA ... and you use persistence.xml when doing that ... again, as per the JPA spec

Comment: HIbernate is a JPA implementation but adds more functionality. you can use the JPA functions, which means that you can change to eclipseLink or any other implementation of JPA. if you use HIbernate specific stuff, you are bound to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a producer to produce the EntityManager. (already doing that)
- Wildfly has the hibernate jars. Use them as provided in your pom.xml. Use the same version as the one provided by wildfly.

Use e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

- Use a persistence.xml file in your META-INF folder. Here is a snippet that can help you. *This requires that you have already setup a myDS datasource in Wildfly.*

  ```
  <persistence-unit name="myDS">
                  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
                  <jta-data-source>java:/myDS</jta-data-source>
                  <properties>
                      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
                      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
                      <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public"/>
                      <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="4"/>                            
                     <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
                      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>
                      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/create-script.sql"/>
                      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script"/>
                      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/drop-script.sql"/>
                      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/sql/data.sql"/>

                      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
                      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="target/jpa/sql/create-schema.sql"/>
                      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="target/jpa/sql/drop-schema.sql"/> -

                      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
                      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="META-INF/sql/data.sql"/> 
                  </properties>
  ```

In order to create automatically the tables from the entities that you have in your projevt you specify drop, create and insert/update sql files to be executed. Already included in the snippet above. Read each property's purpose and use the one that fits your needs in your project.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try all that. I'll be back with more questions :)

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer when you are OK. if you have any other questions, let me know.

Comment: I have set up the datasource and added it to my standalone.xml. But now when starting the server, I get "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections". Where do I need to specify this ? I thought this was the whole point of a Datasource ?

Comment: you setup the datasource from the admin interface. dont try to insert it manyually. go to localhost:8080 and proceed to admin login. you must create the admin user first. it gives you details about what to do. then insert the datasource from the admin web interface

Comment: forgot to mention that you need to deploy first your jdbc driver in wildfly via the admin web console.

Comment: I had already done that. I added the JDBC Driver as Module (instead of deployment). I updated my first post with the CLI output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116545/discussion-between-tim-and-apostolos).

Comment: Util for guide, creating my persistence.xml with tags <property .. />